# Javascript skips else if?

Tags: javascript

Well obivously this will be a stupid mistake of mine because why sould a else if not work?

But well I made a mistake somewhere which I can't find and now my javascript just 'skips' my else if statement in my code.

```
$(window).resize(function(){

    if ($(window).width() <= 1080) {
        responsiveLength = 2;
        maxMargin = -((imgLength - responsiveLength) * imgWidth);
        imgWrapper.css('margin-left','0');
    } else if ($(window).width() <= 700){
        console.log($(window).width());
        maxMargin = -((imgLength - 0) * imgWidth);
        imgWrapper.css('margin-left','0');
    } else {
        responsiveLength = 3;
        maxMargin = -((imgLength - responsiveLength) * imgWidth);    
        imgWrapper.css('margin-left','0');
    }

});
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to swap these two because `700` is less than `1080` and never goes there.

```
if ($(window).width() <= 700) {
  console.log($(window).width());
  maxMargin = -((imgLength - 0) * imgWidth);
  imgWrapper.css('margin-left','0');
} else if ($(window).width() <= 1080) {
  responsiveLength = 2;
  maxMargin = -((imgLength - responsiveLength) * imgWidth);
  imgWrapper.css('margin-left','0');
} else {
  responsiveLength = 3;
  maxMargin = -((imgLength - responsiveLength) * imgWidth);    
  imgWrapper.css('margin-left','0');
}
```

Alternate solution, make sure the window size is more than `700px`:

```
if ($(window).width() <= 1080 && $(window).width() > 700) {
```

**Logic Explained**

Let's consider the logic here.

- ScreenSize: `600px`
  LessThan `1080`? Yes.
  Goes to first block.
- ScreenSize: `1000px`
  LessThan `1080`? Yes.
  Goes to first block.
- ScreenSize: `1600px`
  LessThan `1080`? No.
  Goes to third block.

Answer (score 3):

Arrange the conditions from lowest resolution to highest.

```
if ($(window).width() <= 700) {
    ....
} else if ($(window).width() <= 1080) {
    ....
} else {
    ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you fast answer :D It helped a lot

Comment: Welcome @FlyingUnderpants Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

It won't reach else-if since `$(window).width() <= 1080` implies `$(window).width() <= 700` as well.

I think you want to do

```
if ($(window).width() <= 1080 && $(window).width() > 700) {
    responsiveLength = 2;
    maxMargin = -((imgLength - responsiveLength) * imgWidth);
    imgWrapper.css('margin-left','0');
} else if ($(window).width() <= 700){
    console.log($(window).width());
    maxMargin = -((imgLength - 0) * imgWidth);
    imgWrapper.css('margin-left','0');
} else {
    responsiveLength = 3;
    maxMargin = -((imgLength - responsiveLength) * imgWidth);    
    imgWrapper.css('margin-left','0');
}
```

or reverse the order

```
if ($(window).width() <= 700) {
    responsiveLength = 2;
    maxMargin = -((imgLength - responsiveLength) * imgWidth);
    imgWrapper.css('margin-left','0');
} else if ($(window).width() <= 1080){
    console.log($(window).width());
    maxMargin = -((imgLength - 0) * imgWidth);
    imgWrapper.css('margin-left','0');
} else {
    responsiveLength = 3;
    maxMargin = -((imgLength - responsiveLength) * imgWidth);    
    imgWrapper.css('margin-left','0');
}
```